# C++ constructor and calling function

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I am a C++ learner... I created a simple program wherein I created a constructor and two functions.. my problem is when I create an object and call a function the constructor is not called **(edit:solved!)**.. also how can i call the add function with read function( so that after taking input from the user the program calls the add function and adds the numbers?)

**edit:solved! constructor now works as intended, figured how to make another function call :)**

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class class1
{
    int x,y;
    public:
    class1()
    {
        cout<<"object created\n";
    }
    void read()
    {
        cout<<"enter x";
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"enter y";
        cin>>y;
    }
    int add(int a, int b) //int add()
    {
        int sum=a+b; // int sum=x+y
        cout<<"\nsum=" << sum; // return sum
    }
};
int main()
{
    class1 obj1;
    obj1.read();
    onj1.add(); //this was missing and it didnt work prevuiously

}
```

Comment: I ran your code and the constructor was called. I saw the message "object created" twice. What do you see?

Comment: I don't see object created.. what about the other issue? edit: i can see the object created message now.. don't know what happened earlier

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Do you remember to save file and compile before executing the program?

Comment: @NickyC what about the function call.. how to do it?

Comment: Your "issue #2": Ummm... Just like how you call `obj1.read()`? (The return statement in `add` is missing.)

Comment: @NickyC after making obj1.read() call the console asks me for input now i want it to add those inputs.. i dont think return statement is needed in read().. pardon me if i am wrong

Comment: I repeat: The return statement in `add` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Now that your values are stored in x and y, you can add the values like below:

```
int add() {
  int sum=x+y;
  cout<<"\nsum=" << sum; 
}
```

And call this method from main() after read method

```
obj1.add();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe part of the problem here is that your class is not very meaningful. You don't need a class to add two numbers. But given your code you would write something like

```
obj1.add(10, 20);
```

and the output wuould be

```
sum=30
```

However what I expect you really want to happen is to add two numbers you have previously entered. In that case you need to rewrite your method to use `x` and `y` instead of `a` and `b`

```
int add()
{
    int sum=x+y;
    cout<<"\nsum=" << sum;
}
```

and then

```
int main()
{
    class1 obj1;
    obj1.read();
    obj1.add();
}
```

There's no need for `obj2` in this code.

Comment: @inc.mak There's a list of books here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list Can't make any personal recommendations as I learned C++ a long long time ago. C++ is a complex language and getting a book and doing some proper studying is definitely a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

A return statement is missing in `add` function. Just add a line
  `return sum;` to the end of your `add` function